# Fix Shiny Input

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm making a shiny app that takes a `numericInput(size,...)` and displays a data frame of random numbers with `input$size` rows, and then saves it as a csv. I'm looking for some way to prevent the user of the app to change the inputed number once they have provided it. For example, if the user sees the data frame and thinks "Oh, I don't like these numbers", I want to make sure they cannot just keep entering numbers until they get a result they want (without closing and reopening the app). Is there someway to fix the first input as it is given? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `reactiveValue` and `observeEvent` with the parameter `once = TRUE`

This will allow the reactiveValue to only be set once. The user can then change the input but it will have no effect on the rest of the app

```
size <- reactiveVal()
observeEvent(input$size,{
  size(input$size)
},
once = TRUE)
```

You might have to look into the parameters `ignoreInit` and `ignoreNULL` depending on how you initate your numericInput.